# Модуль decimal: непредвиденное округление до целых

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    with decimal.localcontext() as ctx:
        ctx.prec = 7
        a = decimal.Decimal(15100000)
        b = decimal.Decimal(-2125.234523452345)
        c = a + b  # Decimal('1.509787E+7')
        print(float(c))  # 15097870.0
```

Вот в последней строчке видно, что он округлил не до седьмого знака после запятой, а вообще после седьмого знака.

Что за фигня?

Как сделать, чтобы он округлял именно до седьмого знака после запятой?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы неправильно понимаете значение точности вычислений в классе `Decimal`. Несмотря на то что `Decimal` проектировался для преодоления ограничений `float` (ограниченная точность и принципиальная невозможность точно записать некоторые десятичные дроби, например, 0.3), в его основе лежат аналогичные принципы представления чисел. Любое число в `Decimal` записывается как мантисса умноженная на экспоненту:

```
123.456 = 1.23456 * 10^2
          ^          ^
          |          |
      мантисса   экспонента
```

И точность в `Decimal` влияет на точность десятичного представления мантиссы, а не на количество разрядов после запятой в числе. Точность принимается во внимание во время математических операций:

```
with localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec = 2
    x = Decimal(123.456)
    print(float(x))       # 123.456 - ожидаемо
    y = Decimal(457.789)
    print(float(y))       # 457.789 - ожидаемо
    z = x + y
    print(float(z))       # 580.0, а не 581.24
```

В этом примере при сложении 123.456 (`1.23456 * 10^2`) и 457.789 (`4.57789 * 10^2`) получается `5.81245 * 10^2`. Но так как точность представления мантиссы мы выставили в 2 разряда, лишние разряды округляются, и получается `5.8 * 10^2`, то есть, 580.0.

Если вам нужно округлять числа до определённого знака после запятой, то для этого нужно пользоваться функцией `round()`, а не точностью вычислений `Decimal`:

```
a = Decimal(15100000)
b = Decimal(-2125.234523452345)
c = a + b
print(c)            # Decimal('15097874.76547654765499828500')
print(round(c, 7))  # Decimal('15097874.7654765')
```

Comment: Отличные примеры !

Comment: Очень хорошее объяснение. Спасибо.